# Existence of a countable orthonormal fundamental set in unitary separable spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces

The proof takes a dense set (array) in the space and takes out all the vectors who are a linear combination of its predecessors. It is claimed that with this procedure we get a countable array of linearly independent vectors and by using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization we get the needed set.

I'm confused why must the resulting array be countable? What if there are only finitely many vectors who are linearly independent? I can't see the contradiction here.

Comment: A finite set is countable.

Comment: @J. Loreaux Of course, sorry. We generally used countable meaning only countable and infinite, except in probability classes, never in analysis, so I thought only of infinite sets.

Comment: Is your space infinite dimensional?

Comment: You start with a countable dense set of vectors.

Comment: @user251257 It's not necessarily infinite dimensional. I went through the notes and finite sets are not reffered to as countable so the comment by J. Loreaux is not the answer.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts The density makes it obligatory to be countably infinite?

Comment: If the space isn't infinite dimensional, then any linearly independent set must be finite. You should ask your prof whether he meant "countable and infinite" by "countable".

Comment: @Waddles : The density assumption allows you to start with a finite or countably infinite set. So you don't have to worry about larger infinities. There are larger infinities for sets that are dense, but you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: @Waddles: just because in your notes they generally don't refer to finite sets as countable, they probably don't say explicitly that countable sets are not finite. In common parlance, a set $X$ is countable if there is an injective function $f : X \to \mathbb{N}$. In particular, this allows for finite sets to be countable. If you don't use this definition of countable, then the objection you raised in your question is valid (unless all your vector spaces are infinite dimensional). Ergo, since your vector spaces can be finite dimensional, your professor intends that finite sets are countable.

Comment: @J.Loreaux I'm sure it's meant by infinite countable, but maybe it was left out that we observe only infinite dimensional spaces.
So when the space is infinite dimensional, the resulting set/array cannot be finite?

Comment: @Waddles: I see. Yes, if the space is infinite dimensional, the resulting set cannot be finite. This is because the original countable dense set must have infinitely many linearly independent vectors. Indeed, if it didn't, it would be contained in a finite dimensional subspace and then could not be a dense subset. The last claim follows because there is a hyperplane separating your finite dimensional subspace from any point not in the subspace (here I am assuming you are in a locally convex topological vector space, i.e. the topology is generated by a family of seminorms; this may be overkill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @J.Loreaux actually answered my question (in the lemma from my lectures it was left out that the space is infinite dimensional):

"...If the space is infinite dimensional, the resulting set cannot be finite. This is because the original countable dense set must have infinitely many linearly independent vectors. Indeed, if it didn't, it would be contained in a finite dimensional subspace and then could not be a dense subset. The last claim follows because there is a hyperplane separating your finite dimensional subspace from any point not in the subspace (here I am assuming you are in a locally convex topological vector space, i.e. the topology is generated by a family of seminorms; this may be overkill)"